# Why is text cutting off in SVG Text on Chrome?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a Logo for my new website.

The logo looks great in Firefox but as you can see the `S` on Tomorrow's is cut off in Chrome. Why is this?

http://jsfiddle.net/pro5Lgfx/

```css
body {
  background:black
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="195px" height="53px" viewBox="0 0 195 53" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <title>Logo</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="Your-Score" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <g id="Desktop-Your-Score" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(-23.000000, -24.000000)" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gill Sans" letter-spacing="1.16666663" font-size="28" sketch:alignment="middle" fill="#FFFFFF">
            <g id="Header" sketch:type="MSTextLayer">
                <g id="Primary-Nav-[home]-Copy">
                    <g id="Logo" transform="translate(23.000000, 18.000000)">
                        <text id="TOMORROW’S">
                            <tspan x="0.0328778028" y="26">TOMORROW’S</tspan>
                            <tspan x="36.2975262" y="58">SCORE</tspan>
                        </text>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If depends on the font. On my machine, Seamonkey shows Tomorrow` (without the S) and Chromium has only Tomorrow without the apostrophe even. And, on both browsers the tops of the first line are cut off.

Comment: Jeepers. Is there a better way to resolve this issue across more platforms/systems? Sorely tempted to just export as a PNG :-D

Comment: Why you don't use plain text? Why are you need `svg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pro5Lgfx/4/)
I'm no expert in SVG but After Researching a bit ViewBox is

> viewBox as the "real" coordinate system, it is the coordinate system
>   used to draw the SVG graphics onto the canvas Yo can specify
>   coordinate to viewbox  attribute

Source [MDN ViewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) Source [ViewBox](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/)

<strike>what i came up when i set viewbox width and height to 100% 100% S was visible in chrome as well</strike>

**Update**
well percentage is supported in viewport(i.e width and height) but not in viewbox,better not put viewbox and viewport unless needed (viewport: width=100% and height=100% will not harm the output)

[New DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pro5Lgfx/4/)

**Example**

```
 <svg  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
```

```css
body {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
  <title>Logo</title>
  <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <g id="Your-Score" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Desktop-Your-Score" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(-23.000000, -24.000000)" font-weight="normal" font-family="Gill Sans" letter-spacing="1.16666663" font-size="28" sketch:alignment="middle" fill="#FFFFFF">
      <g id="Header" sketch:type="MSTextLayer">
        <g id="Primary-Nav-[home]-Copy">
          <g id="Logo" transform="translate(23.000000, 18.000000)">
            <text id="TOMORROW’S">
              <tspan x="0.0328778028" y="27">TOMORROW’S</tspan>
              <tspan x="36.2975262" y="58">SCORE</tspan>
            </text>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @michaelmcgurk i have updated and corrected my Answer there  was mistake on viewbox setting attribute you can see on your console i have updated and corrected my answer  plz check it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Will update at my end :-)

Comment: This snippet also cuts off part of the top of the text. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5cmm0.png). This can be solved by simply writing `y="27"` in the first tspan.